# Where to see current encoding of some file in IDEA 13?

Tags: intellij-idea

I know that I can right-click inside any file and choose option `File Encoding` and the popup will appear.

But the popup does not say which encoding is the current file at.

[image]

Do I see file encoding somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the current file encoding in the bottom right of the file window:

[image]

Comment: Me too. Have not seen it before.